# How to cancel app purchases?

Tags: ios-appstore

I tried to purchase something only to realise I didn't have the money in my bank, as this has never happened before I presumed that it just wouldn't work. Obviously it worked and now my App Store is only allowing me to browse the apps but not download or update anything. 
Since this I have tried everything, I have tried to report this to apple to cancel it and I've deleted the app but it has not worked, any advice? I have 10 apps waiting to be updated

Comment: I don't think updates of *other* apps not working have anything to do with purchasing another app.

Comment: I have that same problem..It is related.